# VirtualBox bridged network configuration on Centos 7

Tags: linux, networking, virtualbox

I've used `VBoxManage` command in order to set up a VM. This VM is a `Windows2012_x64` OS type I need to configure network.

As far I've been able to figure out, there are some network modes I could take advantage of in order to set up the guest network configuration:

- NAT
- NAT Service
- Bridge

Seeking on the internet, taking in mind my guest VM is going to bahave as a single server, the best option is to set up a `bridged` network.

I've tried to set it up, nevertheless I'm not been able it works correctly. The command line I've used in order to set the guest network configuration has been:

```
VBoxManage modifyvm $VM --nic1 bridged --bridgeadapter1 e1000g0
```

My host is a CentOS 7.